# How Do I Get By The Basic Authentication Handshake When Using Fiddler To Test A WCF REST Service?

Tags: wcf, rest, fiddler, basic-authentication

How Do I Get By The Basic Authentication Handshake When Using Fiddler To Test A WCF REST Service?

Comment: This is what worked for me!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501701/use-fiddler-with-basic-authentication-to-access-restful-webapi/12502718#12502718

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to base64 encode your username:password and then prefix it with Basic.  It will end up looking something like:

```
Authorization: Basic VEFWSVNcZGFycmVsOg==
```

You then enter this in the request headers field.

Comment: Darrel, what format should the text file that I am encoding be in? It looks like when it gets decoded on the server I am getting ????username@domain.com. I am guessing these are spaces but I don't have any leading spaces in my file.

Comment: @Code Sherpa What textfile?  In the RequestBuilder tab in fiddler, there is a Request Headers textbox.  Just paste your authorization header in there.

Comment: Yes, but the username:password needs to be encoded into a base64 string first... I have a utility that takes a file and outputs the contents to base 64 but am getting leading ????.

Comment: OK, the Fiddler Text Encode/Decode utility worked... I forgot about this. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Code Sherpa I had no idea about that Fiddler utility :-)  Now I do!

Comment: For the record, this handy utility (which I also just discovered) is in `Tools -> Text Encode/Decode...`.

Comment: In Fiddler 4.4.2.1 (beta) it's in `Tools -> Text Wizard`. :)