# Use Fiddler with Basic Authentication to access RESTful WebAPI

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have a WebAPI that works without issue.  I have tested locally and deployed to my server and configured this service in IIS to use Basic Authentication.  I am able to browse to my service and I receive the Authentication challenge I expect and all works swimmingly!  Now I want to use Fiddler to test this and I have constructed a POST to a specific url and I got a 401 (Unauthorized) error.  So I decided to add a base64 string in my Request Header and I am now getting a 500 error.

What I would like to know is, does my Request Header look correct?  I am obviously going to obfuscate my Host and base64 string which contains the format username:password for the Authentication challenge.

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
Content-Length: 185
Content-Type: text/json
Authorization: Basic jskadjfhlksadjhdflkjhiu9813ryiu34
```

Comment: This is where I found the format for Basic Authentication base64 format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: This is where I found a base64 encoder: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: I moved the Authorization up in the list to just below the Host and it works.  I followed the format suggested in the wiki and I think we have everything working. :-)

Answer (score 142):

Fiddler has a tool that does the Base64 for you.  Just create your string: username:password and then go to Tools -> TextWizard and enter the username password combo and choose ToBase64.  Copy and paste that into your Authorization header and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that for next time!

Comment: But how can i send that encoded string along with my json data while json structure is different for sending the data.

Answer (score 23):

AlexGad is right. Once the ToBase64 encoding is created, under the header while composing the request, add the following line:

`Authorization: Basic [encoded_value]`

Now execute the request, it should work! :)

Answer (score 12):

Newer versions of Fiddler (I tested in v4.6.20172.31233) will create and add the necessary `Authorization` header for you *automatically* if you specify the username and password in the Composer URL field like so:

```
https://SomeUser:SomePass@sitename
```

Upon executing, this strips it out of the URL and turns into an HTTP header like:

```
Authorization: Basic U29tZVVzZXI6U29tZVBhc3M=
```

Comment: What if my password contains @ sign?

Comment: Not sure if this works with the new Fiddler (Fiddler Everywhere)... when I try it I get a Bad Request error: [Fiddler] HTTP Request specified an invalid port number.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an older post but when I first was looking at how to do this I came across this post and knew it was the answer but I still didn't know things like did the credentials need to be coma separated etc. So, just in case this might help someone out here are my notes for Fiddler I put together for a JSON POST.

```
First you need to Base64 encode your "username:password"
    • Go to Tools | Text Wizard | To Base64 in dropdown

Post a message in the Composer tab
    • Change the type to POST in the dropdown.
    • Put in the URL
    • Add the following to the top header section.
        ○ Authorization: Basic ReplaceWithYourEncodedCredtials=
        ○ Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    • Add some JSON content to the body
        ○ [{"Address1":null,"Address2":null,"BirthDate":"1967-10-06T00:00:00","City":null,"CompanyHireDate":"2011-06-03T00:00:00","EmailAddress":"myEmail@company.com","EmployeeNumber":"112233","FirstName":"JOHN","LastName":"DOE","PhoneNumber":null,"State":null,"UserName":"JDoe","ZipCode":null}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone who is a newbie like me.

If you are using GET, using **[ ]** around the token would not work.

Following did not work:-

```
Authorization: Basic [MkgzczhaVnhZNG13d1FkTVJ2ZmZMQzFQQnhZRG5WdUVhbDNiVWs0ZldDdzo=]
```

Following worked:-

```
Authorization: Basic MkgzczhaVnhZNG13d1FkTVJ2ZmZMQzFQQnhZRG5WdUVhbDNiVWs0ZldDdzo=
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that in Fiddler 4, all I had to do was check the Automatically Authenticate option that is on the Rules menu.