# Testing ServiceStack Basic authentication

Tags: authentication, servicestack, basic-authentication

ServiceStack provides an example where the different methods of authentication are tested in code. I was trying to build a simple browser test, just to see how it works. 
I basically used this: [ServiceStack Web Service with Basic Authentication and SetCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573793/servicestack-web-service-with-basic-authentication-and-setcredentials) as a base template.

When I go to the metadata page, I see that Auth is listed as one of the available operations.

What do I need to enter as URL, to test whether Auth is working? For example localhost/ServiceStack.Hello/hello/suraj is what I typed in to test the hello world app. How do I test for authentication?

P.s: This is probably a Noob Question, so my apologies in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ServiceStack's [AuthTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AuthTests.cs) for examples on how to test BasicAuth with a C# client.

If you want to do it manually you'll have to use something like Fiddler that will let you manually specify the BasicAuth `Authorization: Basic ...` HTTP Header. See the [wikipedia reference on HTTP BasicAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for an example.