# Basic authentication with service stack

Tags: android, asp.net, apache, mono, servicestack

I am using the JsonServiceClient in my Android application (Written with Xamerin). I have a test client that works with the HelloWorld example given on the servicestack web site. It works just fine without authentication and quickly returns values.

Now I am attempting to bring authentication into the mix, starting with very basic authentication. I have a custom auth and session class on the server that look like this:

```
    public class userSession : AuthUserSession
    {
        public string clientCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class userAuth : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName == "user" || password == "1234") {
                var session = (userSession)authService.GetSession(false);
                session.clientCode = "peruse"; 
                return true ; 
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and that is configured with:

```
        // auth feature and session feature
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new userSession(),
            new[] { new userAuth() }
        ) { HtmlRedirect = null } );
```

On the client side, I am calling up a new JsonServerClient with:

```
JsonServiceClient client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient("http://172.16.0.15/");
```

And an event for a button on the Android interface:

```
            try 
            {
                client.SetCredentials("user", "1234"); 
                HelloResponse response = client.Get<HelloResponse>("/hello/" + toSum.Text);
                txtResult.Text = response.Result ; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                txtResult.Text = ex.Message; 
            }
```

I keep getting a 404 back from the server. When I try to access it with cURL from Linux:

```
curl -v http://user:1234@172.16.0.15/hello/5
```

It returns:

```
*   Trying 172.16.0.15... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET /hello/5 HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjoxMjM0
```

(Other verbose stuff... then...)

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

Along with what looks like a link to a login page:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fhello%2f5">here</a></h2>
</body><html>
```

I've gone into Web.config and removed any reference to this login page, but still it is trying to send me there.

So my question is: Am I sending the credentials the correct way? If so, does the provided code appear to be handling them in a reasonable way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're having the same problem as this poster: [ServiceStack Web Service with Basic Authentication and SetCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13573793/149060)  He managed to get authentication working with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8088/api";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var restClient = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);

        restClient.SetCredentials("john", "test");

        restClient.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true;

        HelloResponse response = restClient.Get<HelloResponse>("/hello/Leniel");

        Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
    }
}

//Response DTO
//Follows naming convention
public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

I recommend reading the entire question and answer, as it includes detailed explanations.